# Restart required after setting system environement variables on Windows8 Enterprise Edition

Tags: java, php, android, windows, environment-variables

Why is environment variables not propagating to all windows. Earlier on my Windows8 machine I had appended environment variables  and it had immediate effect.

After I shifted to a new PC, Windows 8 Enterprise no matter what I try to do environment variables I set are not getting effected. I need to restart my PC for the change to visible.

Environment Variable Appended

> php
>   Location: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\

Similar issue was also faced while setting Java Environment variables and ANDROID_HOME

Is there any way to bypass the Restart required for the environment variable to become available.

Comment: You can try some of the solutions suggested  [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/8855/how-do-you-add-a-windows-environment-variable-without-rebooting)

Answer (score 0):

There is Bypass to Restarting the system after setting the environment variable

On PC's running OS before Windows8

1. Set the Environment variable
2. Open Task Manager
3. Kill explorer.exe
4. Start the explorer.exe using new task in the Task Manager.

On PC's Running Windows8

1. Set the Environment variable
2. Open Task Manager
3. Restart explorer.exe services.

On restarting the explorer service the Environment Variables was seen to get effected for reasons unknown to me.